# jQuery split a table into two tables at a particular row number

Tags: jquery, html

I need to split a table into two tables at a particular row number using jQuery. Can this be done?

I googled but couldn't find anything. jQuery's pretty powerful, I would have thought this can be done.

The table is not numbered so jQuery would need to index the rows.

Any help with this is very much appreciated.

C

Answer (score 9, accepted):

jQuery Slice method will be useful in such case: [documentation here](https://api.jquery.com/slice/)

Add a table with some rows in html:

```
<table id="mainTable">
<tr>
    <td>Row 1</td>
    <td>Dummy Data</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Row 2</td>
    <td>Dummy Data</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Row 3</td>
    <td>Dummy Data</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Row 4</td>
    <td>Dummy Data</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Row 5</td>
    <td>Dummy Data</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Row 6</td>
    <td>Dummy Data</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Row 7</td>
    <td>Dummy Data</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Row 8</td>
    <td>Dummy Data</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Row 9</td>
    <td>Dummy Data</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Row 10</td>
    <td>Dummy Data</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Slice n rows using jQuery, create new table instance and append rows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var $mainTable = $("#mainTable");
    var splitBy = 5;
    var rows = $mainTable.find ( "tr" ).slice( splitBy );
    var $secondTable = $("#mainTable").parent().append("<table id='secondTable'><tbody></tbody></table>");
    $secondTable.find("tbody").append(rows);
    $mainTable.find ( "tr" ).slice( splitBy ).remove();
});
</script>
```

[See working demo here](http://jsbin.com/ruqinudo/2/edit)

Comment: Up for Your code (that it's working correctly of course :D) and  usage of it at other similar question. :)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23774929/splite-one-big-table-in-two-tables-based-on-content-of-third-column-in-each-row/23783302#23783302

Hope You don't mind! :)

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done with clone()

```
var $mainTable = $("table.mainTable");
$mainTable.clone().appendTo($mainTable.parent()).find('tbody tr').slice(0, 4).remove();
$mainTable.find('tbody tr').slice(4).remove();
```