# Split one big table into two tables based on content of third column in each row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table, greasemonkey

Is it possible to have a script for greasemonkey that will split one table on a page into 2 different tables on the basis of one column? So for example I have table:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>Option 1</td>
    <td>5050</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>Option 2</td>
    <td>2353</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Elve</td> 
    <td>Option 1</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And what I want to have as result is:

```
<h2>Table for Option 1</h2>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>Option 1</td>
    <td>5050</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Elve</td> 
    <td>Option 1</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<h2>Table for Option 2</h2>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>Option 2</td>
    <td>2353</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Of course it is possible - write a javascript script ( jquery library will be helpful) that will do that.

Comment: but I have no idea how to do it, can you help me please?

Comment: Do you have any experience with javascript? If not, I suggest starting by googling for some good javascript tutorials and books, and learning the basics.

Comment: Yes, I have basic knowledge of javascript, better said "passive" knowledge when I see code I know what is it doing.

Comment: Geril - my answer has been edited - now You have working script, that needs to be "polished". :) It's spliting table at two, but the conent of new table is not dinamic. You have to do it at Your own.

Answer (score 0):

I needed exactly what the asker requested, split a table based on the contents of a particular column.  Here's my solution:

```
$(function(){
  var redo=true;
  var $mainTable = $("#mainTable");

  while(redo) {
    redo=false;
    var idx=0;
    var myType="-1";

    $mainTable.find("tbody tr>:first-child").each(function() {
      idx=idx+1;
      if(myType=="-1") {
        myType=$(this).text();
      }
      if(myType!=$(this).text())
      {
        var rows = $mainTable.find ( "tr" ).slice( idx );
        var $secondTable = $("<table>"+$mainTable.find("thead")[0].outerHTML+"<tbody></tbody></table>");
        $mainTable.parent().append($secondTable);
        $secondTable.find("tbody").append(rows);
        $mainTable.find ("tr").slice( idx ).remove();
        
        $mainTable=$secondTable;
        myType=$(this).text();
        redo=true;
        return false;
      }
    });
  }
});
```

jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/DKATyler/c278u6vo/37/

Answer (score -1):

Merging answer of @Dharmang from this question: [jQuery split a table into two tables at a particular row number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22266059/jquery-split-a-table-into-two-tables-at-a-particular-row-number)

and my own grease monkey script:

I can give You a preview of greasemonkey script definition but it's not checked and i don't know if this will work for sure (javascript code is correct for 100%):

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        script
// @namespace   http://page.that.script.will.be.runned.at
// @description DESCRIPTION!!!
// @include     http://page.that.script.will.be.runned.at/SOME_PAGE_THAT_SCRIPT_WILL_BE_ACTIVE/*
// @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js
// @require     https://raw.github.com/tomgrohl/jQuery-plugins/master/jcookie/script/jquery.jcookie.min.js
// @version     1
// ==/UserScript==
$(function(){
   console.log('WE HAVE A LIFT OFF!!!! :D SCRIPT IS RUNNING ');
    // YOUR JAVASCRIPT CODE HERE
    // YOU HAVE JQUERY INCLUDED

    var $mainTable = $("table");
    var splitBy = 5;
    var rows = $mainTable.find ( "tr" ).slice( splitBy );
    var $secondTable = $("table").parent().append("<table id='secondTable'><tbody></tbody></table>");
    $secondTable.find("tbody").append(rows);
    $mainTable.find ( "tr" ).slice( splitBy ).remove();

});
```

---

EDIT:

The code below works at http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_table.asp
After 3 second after page load it will split the table for two (the PINK background is Your second table) - You only have to copy table content and replace with splitted values. I WON'T DO ANYTHING FOR YOU!

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        TABLE SPLITTER
// @namespace   http://www.w3schools.com/
// @description DESCRIPTION!!!
// @include     http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_table.asp
// @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js
// @require     https://raw.github.com/tomgrohl/jQuery-plugins/master/jcookie/script/jquery.jcookie.min.js
// @version     1
// ==/UserScript==
$(function(){
        // YOUR JAVASCRIPT CODE HERE
        // YOU HAVE JQUERY INCLUDED
    setTimeout(function(){
        var mainTable = $("table");
        var splitBy = 3;
        var rows = mainTable.find ( "tr" ).slice( splitBy );
        var secondTable = $("<table id='secondTable' style='background:pink;'><tbody></tbody></table>").insertAfter("table");
        secondTable.find("tbody").append(rows);
        console.log(secondTable);
        mainTable.find ( "tr" ).slice( splitBy ).remove();

    }, 3000);
});
```

Comment: Doesn't actually answer the question, this is Dharmang's answer at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22266290/1361991 and splits a table at a row index without locating the relevant row(s) to split at.