# Dividing html table into multiple tables in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

How can I divide html table into multiple tables using jquery, for example I want to divide the table with two rows each and repeat the header. Here is my example of HTML table.

```
    <table border="1" id="mainTable">
    <tr>
        <th>header 1</th>
        <th>header 2</th>
        <th>header 3</th>
        <th>header 4</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Row 1</td>
        <td>Row 1</td>
        <td>Row 1</td>
        <td>Row 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Row 2</td>
        <td>Row 2</td>
        <td>Row 2</td>
        <td>Row 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Row 3</td>
        <td>Row 3</td>
        <td>Row 3</td>
        <td>Row 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Row 4</td>
        <td>Row 4</td>
        <td>Row 4</td>
        <td>Row 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Row 5</td>
        <td>Row 5</td>
        <td>Row 5</td>
        <td>Row 5</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Expected output:

```
    <table border="1" id="mainTable">
    <tr>
        <th>header 1</th>
        <th>header 2</th>
        <th>header 3</th>
        <th>header 4</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Row 1</td>
        <td>Row 1</td>
        <td>Row 1</td>
        <td>Row 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Row 2</td>
        <td>Row 2</td>
        <td>Row 2</td>
        <td>Row 2</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table border="1" id="mainTable">
    <tr>
        <th>header 1</th>
        <th>header 2</th>
        <th>header 3</th>
        <th>header 4</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Row 3</td>
        <td>Row 3</td>
        <td>Row 3</td>
        <td>Row 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Row 4</td>
        <td>Row 4</td>
        <td>Row 4</td>
        <td>Row 4</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table border="1" id="mainTable">
    <tr>
        <th>header 1</th>
        <th>header 2</th>
        <th>header 3</th>
        <th>header 4</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Row 5</td>
        <td>Row 5</td>
        <td>Row 5</td>
        <td>Row 5</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: So... what have you tried already?

Comment: Like taylorc said, you should show us what you tried. You should also look if someone asked it before, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22266059/jquery-split-a-table-into-two-tables-at-a-particular-row-number) is something similar

Comment: Yes, I see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22266059/jquery-split-a-table-into-two-tables-at-a-particular-row-number) similar example but I'm very newbie in jquery and I tried to use this `$("tr:eq(2)")` but I can't get the right output.I'm very sorry for the way I asked coz I did this for the first time and thank you very much for the help guys. :)

Comment: will always get better response (and less downvotes) by posting what you have tried like that...even if it didn't work. People here like to see that some effort was attempted

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want:

```
var $main = $('#mainTable'),
    $head= $main.find('tr:first'),
    $extraRows = $main.find('tr:gt(2)');

for( var i = 0; i < $extraRows.length; i = i+2){
   $('<table>').append($head.clone(), $extraRows.slice(i,i+2)).appendTo($main.parent()); 
}
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/96Lhog5g/3/)**</kbd>

Comment: actually i had fun with this one...making all the manipulation fit in one line

Answer (score 0):

Start by introducing `<thead>` and `<tbody>` sections in your original table. Then iterate through the `tbody` rows and build new tables like so:

```js
$(function() {
  var mt = $('.mainTable'),
      dv = $('<div/>'),
      rows = $('tbody tr',mt).clone(),
      ln = rows.length,
      ntc = 1;
  for( var i = 0; i < ln; i = i + 2 ) {
    var nt = mt.clone().toggleClass('mainTable newTable');
    $('tbody', nt).html( rows.eq(i).clone() );
    if( i + 2 <= ln ) {
      $('tbody',nt).append( rows.eq(i+1).clone() );
    }
    dv.append( '<h1>New Table ' + ntc + '</h1>' );
    dv.append( nt );
    ntc++;
  }
  mt.after( dv.html() );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <table border="1" class="mainTable">
      <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>header 1</th>
        <th>header 2</th>
        <th>header 3</th>
        <th>header 4</th>
    </tr>
        </thead>
      <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Row 1</td>
        <td>Row 1</td>
        <td>Row 1</td>
        <td>Row 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Row 2</td>
        <td>Row 2</td>
        <td>Row 2</td>
        <td>Row 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Row 3</td>
        <td>Row 3</td>
        <td>Row 3</td>
        <td>Row 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Row 4</td>
        <td>Row 4</td>
        <td>Row 4</td>
        <td>Row 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Row 5</td>
        <td>Row 5</td>
        <td>Row 5</td>
        <td>Row 5</td>
    </tr>
        </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you so much @PeterKA with your very good instructions above :)